# Changing the color of input if Email1 and Email2 Duplicated

Tags: html, angular, typescript

If the Email1 and Email is duplicated the border of input email1 and email2 will change to the color red.

What will I do?
Use `*ngIf="Profile.AuthorizedRep1Email === Profile.AuthorizedRep2Email"`?
Make a function?
Or what?
Any suggestion?

```
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">

    <div class="input-container">
        <label for="Representative1">* Email</label>
        <input name="r1email" #r1email="ngModel" id="Representative1Email" type="email" [(ngModel)]="Profile.AuthorizedRep1Email" placeholder="email@email.com" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$" pInputText required />
        <div class="errortxt" [hidden]="r1email.valid || r1email.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">
            <div class="errortxt" [hidden]="!r1email.hasError('required')">Email is Required!</div>
            <div class="errortxt" [hidden]="!r1email.hasError('pattern')">Invalid Format!</div>
        </div>
    </div>

  <div class="input-container">
      <label for="Representative2">* Email</label>
      <input name="r2email" #r2email="ngModel" id="Representative2Email" type="email" [(ngModel)]="Profile.AuthorizedRep2Email" placeholder="email@email.com" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$" pInputText required />
      <div class="errortxt" [hidden]="r2email.valid || r2email.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">
          <div class="errortxt" [hidden]="!r2email.hasError('required')">Email is Required!</div>
          <div class="errortxt" [hidden]="!r2email.hasError('pattern')">Invalid Format!</div>
      </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: [ngStyle]="{'border-color': yourCondition ? '' : 'red'}" Try adding this to both the inputs

Comment: Why not use ngClass?
so say `[ngClass]="Profile.AuthorizedRep1Email === Profile.AuthorizedRep2Email ? 'failClass' : 'successClass'"`?

Comment: Yeah, or `ngStyle` will work too.  I am just not a big fan of inline styling.

Comment: you can use both. In this case, it is just adding one attribute. So, I used ngStyle

Answer (score 0):

Add a error class on the input if both the emails match    `[ngClass]="{'error': Profile.AuthorizedRep1Email==c.AuthorizedRep2Email}"`

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">    
    <div class="input-container">
        <label for="Representative1">* Email</label>
        <input [ngClass]="{'error': Profile.AuthorizedRep1Email===Profile.AuthorizedRep2Email}" name="r1email" #r1email="ngModel" id="Representative1Email" type="email" [(ngModel)]="Profile.AuthorizedRep1Email" placeholder="email@email.com" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$" pInputText required />
        <div class="errortxt" [hidden]="r1email.valid || r1email.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">
            <div class="errortxt" [hidden]="!r1email.hasError('required')">Email is Required!</div>
            <div class="errortxt" [hidden]="!r1email.hasError('pattern')">Invalid Format!</div>
        </div>
    </div>

  <div class="input-container">
      <label for="Representative2">* Email</label>
      <input [ngClass]="{'error': Profile.AuthorizedRep1Email===Profile.AuthorizedRep2Email}" name="r2email" #r2email="ngModel" id="Representative2Email" type="email" [(ngModel)]="Profile.AuthorizedRep2Email" placeholder="email@email.com" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$" pInputText required />
      <div class="errortxt" [hidden]="r2email.valid || r2email.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">
          <div class="errortxt" [hidden]="!r2email.hasError('required')">Email is Required!</div>
          <div class="errortxt" [hidden]="!r2email.hasError('pattern')">Invalid Format!</div>
      </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.error {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `[ngClass]="{'is-valid': validateEmail()}"` for both input DOM elements and return two or false

Comment: I would not use this solution, as it is very expensive performance-wise. Angular will call the method on every DOM action, since it can't watch a method for changes.